# Angular boostrap-ui datepicker dynamically changing minMode

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

So I have datepicker where changing tabs day/month/year should change minMode of datepicker

```
 switch($rootScope.tab){

    case 'd':
      $scope.datePicker = 'day';
      $scope.dateOptions = {minMode : 'day'};
      break;
    case 'm':
      $scope.datePicker = 'month';
      $scope.dateOptions = {minMode: 'month', datepickerMode: 'month'};
      break;
    case 'y':
      $scope.datePicker = 'year';
      $scope.dateOptions = {minMode : 'year'};
      break;
    case 't':
      $scope.datePicker = 'none';
      $scope.dateOptions = {minMode : 'none'};
  }
```

the problem is that datepicker updates fine but dateOptions just ignores minMode and still lets you select day instead of month/year and so. DatePicker in view

```
<span  
    type="hidden" 
    style="display: none;" 
    class="form-control" 
    datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
    ng-model="dt" 
    is-open="opened" 
    min-date="{{minDate}}" 
    max-date="{{maxDate}}" 
    datepicker-mode="datePicker"
    datepicker-options="dateOptions"
    ng-required="true" 
    close-text="Close"/>
```

Is there workaround for this like redrawing datepicker everytime tab changes?(datepicker is outside tabset).

Comment: the issue is same as https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2618 last comments.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution I came a cross was to use https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker and then create 3 buttons for showing calendar with different startView(minMode) and minView(datePicker) while using ng-show to show/hide different one of them depending on which tab/button was pressed. Apparently this method doesn't work on bootstrap-ui angular datepicker.

Comment: Nice! Can you post an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `ui-bootstrap-tpls` link basically copies the values from the options object **during initialisation only**, so you're not going to see these change dynamically:

```
  var datepickerEl = angular.element(popupEl.children()[0]);
  if ( attrs.datepickerOptions ) {
    angular.forEach(scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.datepickerOptions), function( value, option ) {
      datepickerEl.attr( cameltoDash(option), value );
    });
  }
```

In my opinion this is unexpected behaviour for an AngularJS directive where model updates are reflected in the DOM and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be able to use `$broadcast` events with the `configureOn` option to re-configure the https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker when you switch tabs.  See https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker#configureon